# Is there a way to have Windows task scheduler automatically respond to input() in Python script?

Tags: python, input, scheduled-tasks

I'm trying to schedule a python script to run automatically on a Windows 10 machine. The script, when run alone, prompts the user for some input to use as it runs. I'd like to automatically set these inputs when the scheduler runs the `.bat` file. As an example:

`test.py`:

```
def main():
    name = input('What is your name? ')
    print(f'Hello, {name}. How are you today?')

main()
```

This works fine if I just run the script, but ideally I'd like to have the `name` variable passed to it from the `.bat` file.

`test.bat`:

```
"path\to\python.exe" "path\to\test.py"
pause
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: you can redirect data from file `script.py <data.txt` File need text with enter (new line) at the end.

Comment: you could use `sys.argv` in script to get arguments `script.py "James Bond"`. Script could check if `len(sys.argv) > 1` and get name from `sys.argv[1]`. If len is 1 then it could use `input()` to ask user.

Comment: If you want to give a fixed input (not from a file), you can do it like `echo name_for_python | "path\to\python.exe" "path\to\test.py"`.

Comment: @jdehesa Thank you! This works. Is it possible to pass multiple arguments to the script this way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want to give a single fixed input, you can do it like:

```
REM If you add extra spaces before `|` those will be passed to the program
ECHO name_for_python| "path\to\python.exe" "path\to\test.py"
```

Unfortunately, there is no good way of extending this to multiple lines. You would use a file containing the lines you want to input for that:

```
"path\to\python.exe" "path\to\test.py" < file_with_inputs.txt
```

If you want to have everything into a standalone script, you may do something like this:

```
REM Choose some path for a temporary file
SET temp_file=%TEMP%\input_for_my_script
REM Write input lines to file, use > for first line to make sure file is cleared
ECHO input line 1> %temp_file%
REM Use >> for remaining lines to append to file
ECHO input line 2>> %temp_file%
ECHO input line 3>> %temp_file%
REM Call program with input file
"path\to\python.exe" "path\to\test.py" < file_with_inputs.txt
REM Delete the temporary file
DEL %temp_file% /q
```

Obviously, this is assuming you cannot use the standard [`sys.argv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.argv) (or extensions like [`argparse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html)), which would be the more standard and convenient way to send arguments to a script.